# Hide Title of Button in ios Swift and show image instead

Tags: ios, swift, button

I want to hide the Label text of a button onClick and instead show an image.
On a second click, the title should appear again.

Sadly, the title disappears and the color of the button changes but there is no image shown and on click it never enters the "else"-Part of the if/else where the label should appear back again, so "2" is never printed.
What is the error?

```
if (button10.titleLabel!.text != "") {
            print("1")

            button10.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
            button10.setImage(UIImage(named: "1.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        }
        else if (button10.titleLabel!.text == ""){
            print("2")
            button10.setTitle("String", forState: .Normal)
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove/change the image for the button too:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
var clicked = false

@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (clicked){
        clicked = false
        button.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "black"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    else{
        clicked = true
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: ""), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.setTitle("Clicked", forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

And to change the image for a `UIButton` use `setBackgroundImage`

Comment: The Image wasn't shwn because I forgot to set the button from system to custom. Thanks for your tips